# Round numbers > two decimals

Tags: java

I want the following code to show only rounded numbers by two decimals . . .

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double gross = 4322.12d;
        double tax = 397.04d;

        double net = gross - tax;
        double fee = gross * 0.30d;
        double vat = fee * 0.20d;
        double takeHome = net - (fee + vat);

        System.out.println("Gross Refund £" + gross);
        System.out.println("Tax Deducted £" + tax);
        System.out.println("Net Refund £" + net);
        System.out.println("Our Fee £" + (fee + vat));
        System.out.println("Funds remaining after deductions £" + takeHome);

    }

}
```

Comment: Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: Use `printf()`, as in: `System.out.printf("Gross Refund £%.2f%n", gross);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did some changes in your code check this:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

double gross = 4322.12d;
double tax = 397.04d;

double net = gross - tax;
double fee = gross * 0.30d;
double vat = fee * 0.20d;
double takeHome = net - (fee + vat);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println("Gross Refund :" + df.format(gross));
System.out.println("Tax Deducted :" + df.format(tax));
System.out.println("Net Refund :" + df.format(net));
System.out.println("Our Fee :" + df.format(fee + vat));
System.out.println("Funds remaining after deductions :" +df.format(takeHome));
}
}
```